# Failed to Convert date('Yzhis') to Y-m-d in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-conversion

I am trying to convert the following dates:

```
$myDate=
```

201373055607

201373055616

201594035728

201373102215

2013160023556

etc...

They created by that function:

```
date('Yzhis')
```

And I want to convert them into that format: 'Y-m-d'
So, I used that code:

```
$old_date = $myDate;            

$middle = strtotime($old_date);          

$new_date = date('Y-m-d', $middle);
```

And it returns me the following:

5607-08-17

5616-08-17

5728-08-17

1970-01-01

2013-06-09

etc...

As you can see the first 4 dates are wrong and only the last one is correct.

How to bypass that convertion error and return the proper date ??

Answer (score 2):

`Yzhis` is *not* [a valid date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). As a result `strtotime()` fails and returns false, or worse, the value it *thinks* is a date can be converted into a date but one that really makes no sense.

If you're going to use a non-standard format (which you probably do not need to do), you would need to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to be able to handle it properly.

```
$old_date = $myDate;            
$middle = DateTime::createFromFormat('Yzhis', $old_date);
$new_date = $middle->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/419297)

Comment: Yes. But since PHP 5.5 is the oldest supported version of PHP that shouldn't be much of an issue anymore.

Comment: Yep. Both of you have right. I forgot that I have already the latest supported version in the machine. John, I will check your answer as soon as possible and I will give you the feedback. But I am pretty sure that it will work.

Comment: @JohnConde I have the following error:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object in ....

Comment: Greg, I added a demo to show it works. If it doesn't work for you then you are doing something than described here.